# jquery slider jump to height glitch

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-ui-accordion

Does anybody know how to fix the glitch in jquery where the sliding block jumps into place when it is a large block being slid.

Example

http://jsbin.com/emoba5/5/edit

Click on posture two to see the jump. I have seen some fixes like this one

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/

but have no idea how to implement it to my code?

Thanks for having a look :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the container you're sliding a width, like this:

```
.toggle_container .block { width: 200px; }
```

I know I sound crazy, but trust me on this one.  [Here's your example with the above CSS working](http://jsbin.com/emoba5/6/edit).

Comment: A+++ would use this tip again!